# JS: How to remove element from an array if found?

Tags: javascript

so I was using  this code to find a value in an array and delete it if found:

```
var index2 = myarray.indexOf(mystring);
if(index2 > -1){
  myarray.splice(index2, 1);
}
```

However, myarray is changing very often. So sometimes, do you think it could possible that when I do splice, the index2 value is not the right on anymore?

How can I remove a value from an array if it has been found being sure at 100% the good value is deleted?

Answer (score 3):

> So sometimes, do you think it could possible that when I do splice, the index2 value is not the right on anymore?

Not in the vast majority of JavaScript environments, no, because in those environments (browsers, NodeJS, etc.) all of the code with access to that array is run on a *single thread* which is never interrupted in the middle of processing a *task* (as the HTML spec calls them; the ES6 spec calls them *jobs*). (Other than a couple of edge cases around `alert` and such in Firefox, but your code isn't using them.) So nothing can come along after your `indexOf` but before your `splice` if they're one right after the other as shown.

There *are* environments where JavaScript is not single-threaded. The most common one is the Java virtual machine, which can run JavaScript code via the Rhino and Nashorn ("nass-horn") scripting engines.

You can have multiple threads on browsers, too, via [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), but they can only communicate via messaging, so two separate threads can't update the same array.

Comment: What if my code is called in a different setTimeOut? So asynchronously. (I am using node.JS)

Comment: @lopata: If you have `indexOf`, and then you have `splice` in a function you're passing to `setTimeout` or `nextTick`, then sure, something else could be given the thread after the `indexOf` and before the `splice`. But I can't think of any reason you'd do that. You'd do the `indexOf` immediately before calling `splice`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, no operations will occur between the time you call `indexOf` and the time you call `splice`. Even if there are, say, asynchronous operations pending in the event loop that will modify the array, those operations will happen before or after this code and never in the middle.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. If you're super concerned, you can look into [immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) which essentially does the same thing as your code or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#without) to help you out with manipulating arrays.